# Angular 5: Render blank url with src until variables resolved

Tags: angular

If I have inside my template

```
<img src="/somepath/{{user?.UserGuid}}.png" />
```

If `user` has not resolved yet, then `?.` will prevent evaluating `UserGuid`, however this will render:

```
<img src="/somepath/.png" />
```

Without using `*ngIf` or using a function to have to check if a variable isn't resolved, how can I stop this behaviour? Perhaps by rendering a blank url. Do I have to do:

```
<img [src]="user ? '/somepath/' + user.UserGuid + '.png' : ''" />
```

As this seems prone to error with more complex urls and is not easy to read

Comment: Why do you not want to use `*ngIf`?

Comment: Because this causes elements to appear or disappear. The link should still be visible without content moving on the page.

Comment: Try This `<img src="imagenotfound.gif" alt="Image not found" onerror="this.onerror=null;this.src='imagefound.gif';" />`

Comment: You could have a blank placeholder image called e.g. `blank.png`, then use `{{user?.UserGuid || 'blank'}}`.

Comment: @DarthJDG That's a clever idea. The only problem is that every image path now has to have a default image

Comment: You could go with your second option then, or have two `<img>` tags, one with `*ngIf="user"`, the other with `*ngIf="!user"`. Either way, it won't be so pretty. :)

Comment: You could also move the URL generation code into a method on your component and bind it to the src property, e.g. `<img [src]="getURL(user)">`.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps not for everyone, but I have created a custom directive to get round this issue. It can be used with either a single object to be resolved, or an array of objects. When all evaluate to true then `src` attribute will be set.

Single object:

```
<img [cdSrcResolve]="user" cdSrc="{{state.imagePath}}/{{user.UserGuid}}.png" />
```

Array of objects:

```
<img [cdSrcResolve]="[state, user]" cdSrc="{{state.imagePath}}/{{user.UserGuid}}.png" />
```

and the directive:

```
import { Renderer, ElementRef, Directive, OnChanges, SimpleChanges, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[cdSrcResolve]'
})
export class SrcResolveDirective implements OnChanges {
  @Input() cdSrcResolve: object;
  @Input() cdSrc: object;

  constructor(private el: ElementRef,
    private renderer: Renderer) { }

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    let currentValue = changes.cdSrcResolve.currentValue;
    currentValue = Array.isArray(currentValue) ? currentValue : [currentValue];
    this.renderer.setElementAttribute(this.el.nativeElement, 'src', currentValue.every(x => !!x) ? changes.cdSrc.currentValue : '');
  }
}
```